# What's wrong when code first reverse engineering with a table name "Object"

Tags: entity-framework

I was using Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 2 to reverse engineering Code First. In the DB there's a table name "Object".

When I test, it gives me this error:

The type 'TestEFPowerTools.Models.Object' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive, nested or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.

After I comment out

```
public DbSet<Object> Objects { get; set; }

modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ObjectMap());
```

in the Context file, everything works fine. How do I fix it or Is it a bug in the power tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Object is a reserved word in C#, [the base class for everything](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx), although you may be able to get around this by mapping renaming the class to something other than object, and mapping to the object table, using fluent or data annotations.  I would rename the table if possible though.

Change your classname from Object to something else, ObjectData for example.  Rename all the references to Object to ObjectData:

```
public class ObjectData ()
{

}

public DbSet<ObjectData> ObjectDatas {get;set;}
```

In the configuration, add a mapping to a different table:

```
public class ObjectData Map : EntityTypeConfiguration<ObjectData>
{
  public ObjectDataMap()
   {
     //other mappings
     this.ToTable("Object");
   }

}
```

Comment: Nit: `Object` is *not* a reserved word. `object` is. `Object` *normally* reasolves to `System.Object`, but this can be changed with different `using`s .. although I suspect that having it map to another name would still fix/avoid the issue.

Comment: I have no priviledge to modify the table name. What's the best way to fix the issue without renaming?